# Symfony2 parameters and subparameters

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to configure my app in this way:
parameters.yml:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: db_prod
    database_user: root
    database_password: pass
    testing:
        database_host: 127.0.0.1
        database_port: null
        database_name: db_test
        database_user: root
        database_password: pass
```

and in config_test.yml I have:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%testing.database_host%"
        port:     "%testing.database_port%"
        dbname:   "%testing.database_name%"
        user:     "%testing.database_user%"
        password: "%testing.database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

But symfony throws ParameterNotFoundExceptio. So - probably I can't do it by dot symbol.
How can I get this parameters under **testing header** in config_test.yml file?

Comment: The parameter names will not be resolved by *going into* the values. Which means if you want to inject them directly, you'll need to name them `testing.database_host` (and so on).

Comment: Yes. It works. But doesn't look good in file. But... works :) Thanks.

Comment: "testing" is an array, for processing it you have to add appropriate functionality to class where you need to use this array. for example, if you pass `"%testing%"` to class in your `parameters.yml` and then call `$this->container->getParameter('testing');` you will get simple php array.